# Rails Minitest system test to accept dialog box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Rails minitest [system test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) with a modal/confirmation dialog box.

How do I accept/reject it?

```
link_to "Delete", user_path(@user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure" }
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is no Minitest specific solution System tests use Capybara which supports modal dialog boxes with the following syntax:

```
accept_confirm do
  # test what happens on confirmation
end
```

There is also an option to verify the displayed prompt:

```
accept_confirm 'Are you sure?' do
  # test what happens on confirmation
end
```

There are plenty of other ways of working with modal dialog boxes:

```
dismiss_confirm do
  # test what happens on dismissing
end
```

See documentation for `accept_alert`, `dismiss_confirm`, `accept_prompt`

[Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara#Modals)
[Introduced Capybara 2.4.1](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-241)